# Bulk create duplicate model plus objects linked by foreign keys linked to that model

Tags: python, django

I have two database models, let's call them:

```
class People(models.Model):
   current_job = models.ForeignKey(Job, blank=True)

class Job(models.Model):
   job_title = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=False)
```

So a People object can have a job which is stored in a separate table and linked via a foreign key. Now I need to duplicate large sections of this table based on a group of people (let's say all people under 40). All properties are same except they're new objects - links should persist between these two new duplicated objects (new_person-new_job should reflect original_person-original_job link).

The tables are large; this query results in 1 million objects of people and 400k jobs linked as foreign keys, so I want to bulk create this because doing this in a for loop (for each person, get their job, mint new person, mint new job) takes forever.

Is there a smart way of bulk creating these two query sets together such that the foreign key relation persists for the copied items?

Any help is appreciated, been driving me nuts last few days!

Comment: Are you sure you want to duplicate? Duplicated records and a SQL Database doesn't seem correct (in most scenarios)

Comment: Yeah - it's about duplicating an existing set of records for repurposing for new analysis which will modify the content of those records in the process (not actually jobs and people I should add). So original always needs to persist.